# IOPCIDevice not linked when loading kext

Tags: iokit, pci, kernel-extension

I am trying to write a driver for a PCI composite video capture card for OSX.

The kext builds just fine, but when I try to load it, I get this:

```
Diagnostics for /System/Library/Extensions/Conexant878.kext:
Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
WARNING - Invalid signature -67030 0xFFFFFFFFFFFEFA2A for kext "/System/Library/Extensions/Conexant878.kext"
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]:     __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice16Ev
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]:     __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice17Ev
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]:     __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice18Ev
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]:     __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice19Ev
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]:     __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice20Ev
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]:     __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice21Ev
(kernel) kxld[com.akasaka.Conexant878]:     __ZN11IOPCIDevice24getDeviceMemoryWithIndexEj
(kernel) Can't load kext com.akasaka.Conexant878 - link failed.
(kernel) Failed to load executable for kext com.akasaka.Conexant878.
(kernel) Kext com.akasaka.Conexant878 failed to load (0xdc008016).
(kernel) Failed to load kext com.akasaka.Conexant878 (error 0xdc008016).
Failed to load /System/Library/Extensions/Conexant878.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
Check library declarations for your kext with kextlibs(8).
```

The kextlibs output is as follows:

```
For all architectures:
    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily = 2.9
    com.apple.kpi.iokit = 13.4
    com.apple.kpi.libkern = 13.4

For x86_64:
    7 symbols not found in any library kext:
    __ZN11IOPCIDevice24getDeviceMemoryWithIndexEj
    __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice16Ev
    __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice18Ev
    __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice20Ev
    __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice17Ev
    __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice19Ev
    __ZN11IOPCIDevice22_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice21Ev
```

My Info.plist contains all of the OSBundleLibraries I could think of being necessary in this context, but that is still a no-go:

```
...
    <key>IOClass</key>
    <string>ConexantTuner</string>
    <key>OSBundleRequired</key>
    <string>Local-Root</string>
    <key>IOPCIMatch</key>
    <string>0x036e109e</string>
    <key>IOProviderClass</key>
    <string>IOPCIDevice</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily</key>
        <string>1.0.0b1</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.unsupported</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.bsd</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What else can I attempt to determine what else I need to depend upon in order to get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

C++Filt output of the unresolved symbols:

```
IOPCIDevice::getDeviceMemoryWithIndex(unsigned int)
IOPCIDevice::_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice16()
IOPCIDevice::_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice18()
IOPCIDevice::_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice20()
IOPCIDevice::_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice17()
IOPCIDevice::_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice19()
IOPCIDevice::_RESERVEDIOPCIDevice21()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a mismatch between the SDK version you are building against and the OS X version you are trying to load your kext on. Unlike OS X userspace, setting the "Deployment Target" to the minimum OS X version supported by your driver is not sufficient. You must also use the OS X SDK version matching the oldest supported OS X version for this very reason of reserved virtual functions.

So e.g. maybe you're building with the 10.10 or 10.11 SDK, but are trying to load the kext on 10.9. That won't work. Use Xcode 6.3.2 (the newest version that ships with the 10.9 SDK), select the 10.9 SDK, and build with that.

Comment: The GetDeviceMemoryWithIndex problem is now gone, but the rest is still present :(

Comment: Very strange. Have you got any custom header search paths set or anything like that? Any special linker flags, such as making symbols hidden? On closer review, your `info.plist` doesn't look quite right either. Specifically, your `IOKitPersonalities` dictionary is empty, but you have some IOKit matching keys in the root. Those should almost certainly be in a personality. They shouldn't cause link errors though.

Comment: is there a personality for IOKit PCI extensions?

Comment: The properties for matching your device (IOPCIDevice provider class, and usually vendor id, product id) and generating your driver instance need to be in a iokit personality dictionary.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Matching/Matching.html